Installing soketi on my kubuntu 22.04 I got node version error... How better to fix it?
I have installed soketi on my kubuntu 22.04 but starting it I got an error :
$ soketi start
/usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws.js:22
throw new Error('This version of uWS.js supports only Node.js 14, 16 and 18 on (glibc) Linux, macOS and Windows, on Tier 1 platforms (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#platform-list).\n\n' + e.toString());
^

Error: This version of uWS.js supports only Node.js 14, 16 and 18 on (glibc) Linux, macOS and Windows, on Tier 1 platforms (https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/BUILDING.md#platform-list).

Error: Cannot find module './uws_linux_x64_115.node'
Require stack:
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/dist/server.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/dist/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/dist/cli/cli.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/dist/cli/index.js
- /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/bin/server.js
at /usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws.js:22:9
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/node_modules/uWebSockets.js/uws.js:24:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/@soketi/soketi/dist/server.js:18:13)
        at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)

        Node.js v20.12.2

I have in my OS :
$ node -v
v20.12.2
$ npm -v
10.5.0


$ uname -a

lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Linux master-at-home 6.5.0-28-generic #29~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 14:39:20 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
6.5.0-28-generic
x86_64

Looks like I have too high node version? Have I reduce version of node on my OS till 18? In which way is it better to do?
